# Scripting with alternate credentials and the difference between PSexec, Explorer shell, and Start-Process -Credential

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I've run into an interesting problem which I can't quite figure out. I have a script which is intended to launch a certain application with alternate credentials. I can launch the application perfectly well using alternate creds using explorer and right clicking and choosing "Run As Different User" or with "PSexec - domain\user -p password "c:\app.exe"" but if I attempt to launch using:

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
Start-Process c:\app.exe -Credential ($credentials)
```

The application does in fact start using the alternate credentials but it then gets stuck in a loop/crashes. Using procmon it looks like it gets stuck on querying a directory that the app uses for caching, but I'm not sure it's relevant. I did try completely opening up the app folder ACL's (and all child objects recursively) to everyone but no luck. If I substitute other applications it works properly. I've used the "powershell" method to specify alt credentials with success many times before.

In any case, the script works fine using PSexec. I'd rather not have that dependency but it works for now. My question is, what is the difference from using the "powershell way" (using System.Management.Automation.PSCredential) to specify alternate credentials vs what PSexec or explorer is doing under the hood? I assume there must be something different going on and perhaps that information could help me trace why the application borks.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the technet pages of [Start-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) and [Psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) there is a difference in how the user profile is handled by default.

Start-Process does not load the profile unless you specify a switch:

> -LoadUserProfile
>
> Loads the Windows user profile stored in the HKEY_USERS registry key
>   for the current user. The default value is FALSE.

Psexec does always load the profile unless you specify a switch:

> -e    Does not load the specified account’s profile.

If the program expects some registry value for the cache location e.g. this could be a potential problem.